# 502.3 Bad Gateway error page when Core site sits on breakpoint for a while

Tags: debugging, iis, asp.net-core

I am working on a large legacy web application, just converted to .Net Core. It targets net47 (not netstandard).

Because it consists of multiple sites, it has to run in IIS whilst I'm debugging it.

When it hits a breakpoint when I hit a page and I leave it sitting there, then after a while IIS sends this error page to the browser:

HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

What can I do to stop this behaviour? I don't want it to time out at all.

Comment: ANCM has a 2 minute timeout you can change in the web.config

Comment: see requestTimeout  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module

Comment: That worked! If you make your comment into an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANCM has a 2 minute timeout you can change in the web.config.
See requestTimeout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module